# Testcafe: Is there a way to get testcafe reverse proxy URL?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, testcafe

When we run a test in testcafe, it uses reverse proxy. Is there a way to get that prefix URL - http://{hostname}:{port}/randomString in the test.

When I try to use Client Function - I get only the URL without this prefix URL

```
const getURL = ClientFunction(() => window.location.href);
const myUrl = await getURL();
```

Is there a way to get testcafe reverse proxy URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no public API to get proxy URL.
You can use some internal methods to get the page url with proxy prefix:

```
window['%hammerhead%'].utils.url.getProxyUrl('')
```

However, this is a private API and it is not recommended for use in your testing scenarios.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this. 
I want to integrate testcafe with lighthouse for authenticated application. As testcafe works on reverse proxy all the session/local storage are stored with proxy URL. I need this URL to pass on to lighthouse to get score of the authenticated page as it opens a new tab in testcafe.